# Lack of understanding crash report from apple review

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

During review, your app crashed on iPad running iOS 8.1.2 when we tap the login button on the first page.

This occurred when your app was used:
- Offline
- On Wi-Fi
- On cellular network

We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

I have tested latest release on iPad 2 , iPad air simulator and even in iPad devices. Its working fine. I have tested it in IOS 8.1.3 because this is the latest update. How we test it in IOS 8.1.2.

I also matched UUID of release , and crash log UUID its same. i followed all the guide.  How i follow my issue , i did't find this bug in my app.

Comment: can you show the crash logs they have provided?

Comment: What does the crash log say?